# Put two checkboxes horizontally, one beside the other, in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a form with this code, with two checkboxes at the end of it. What I want is that the checkboxex align horizontally one beside the other:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CategoriaId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NombreCategoria)
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NombreCategoria, "Tipo de Producto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label class="form-control-static" style="color:#ff6a00">@Model.NombreCategoria</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Titulo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Titulo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Titulo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descripcion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Descripcion, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 3 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Precio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Precio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Precio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactoTelefono, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ContactoTelefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactoTelefono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>


            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactoMail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ContactoMail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactoMail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the checkboxes are displayed with a huge space between them. I want to put them more together.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you provide the resulting HTML and the CSS, so that we can see for ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

Like [this sample?](https://jsfiddle.net/thg1gpfc/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control checkbox-inline" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control checkbox-inline" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.checkbox-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but adding a label before each checkbox.

Comment: And using Html.LabelFor and Html.CheckBoxFor, how would be?

Comment: @Levimatt Your checkboxes are in different divs. Until we know what the CSS for those divs looks like, we can't say anything about it.

Comment: I use standard css bootstrap with no modification on it.